# How do I get rid of "TypeError: List cannot be interpreted as integer" when I am fairly sure I'm not representing the list as an integer?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am working on the table printer project in the Automate the Boring textbook and cannot seem to figure out why I am receiving the error I mentioned in the title.

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

col_width = 0

def print_table(list):
    
    col_width = [0] * len(list)
    
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(i):
            if len(list[i][j]) > col_width[i]:
                col_width[i] = len(list[i][j])
            else:
                continue
   
    for item in list:
        for j in range(len(item)):
            item[j] = (item[j].rjust(col_width))
    
    for i in range(len(list[0])):
        for j in range(len(list)):
            print(str(list[j][i]), end = '')
        print()

print_table(tableData)
```

That is my code, and the error is occurring on this line:

```
item[j] = (item[j].rjust(col_width))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: But `col_width` IS a list!

Comment: col_width has been redefined as a list. You are referring col_width as though it is an integer.   col_width = [0] * len(list).  You are later using item[j] = (item[j].rjust(col_width)). You may want use a number here instead of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to say....

```
for item in list:
    for j in range(len(item)):
        item[j] = (item[j].rjust(0)) #instead of col_width ?
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code **col_width** is passing a list not an integer, that is why is giving you the error.